# Does the .xap file contain "x:name" for the Silverlight app components?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-applications, telerik

I am trying to find some sort of identifier (x:name for example) for some input text boxs and buttons within [this](http://sapbydesign.com) Silverlight web app. As I couldn't find anything in the website source, I located the client .xap file for this app. I decompiled it using Telerik JustDecompile and ended up with a bunch of .dll files which show [this](http://s95.photobucket.com/user/examoprh/media/decomp_zpsb2478fba.png.html).

I don't really know where to go now from here to find these identifiers or if they even exist therefore, would appreciate some advise on if I am heading down the right track and what my next steps should be.

Comment: Sorry amigo, you may run into a lack of cooperation from folks around here to help you reverse-engineer someone else's work. It would probably get you more assistance if you just identified what you're trying to do, made an effort on your own, and came back with your specific issues so we can help put you on the right track of building it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am trying to automate the website logging in procedure. The question simply is just "how do I find the element name" for example on a HTML website, I can inspect the element, what is the equivelent on a Silverlight app?

Comment: You could throw the xap at something like .net reflector, but sorry I don't have much experience reverse-engineering.

Comment: This is the reason some of us use SL. It is a little more secure and harder for you to get this info. BTW, Silverlight controls don't REQUIRE identifiers (same as WPF) which reduces memory and handles. I don't think you can get what you want.